# Why I get exception when setting ComboBox.SelectedIndex?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp, winrt-xaml

I am trying to learn about bindings and XAML. I have a very simple example, where I bind an array of strings to a combobox defined in XAML. I also want to set the selected index.

I am getting an exception:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

with the *SelectedIndex* property.

Here my XAML for a UWP application.

```xml
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource applicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ComboBox Name="BrowserCombo" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboStrings}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

and the code behind

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private string[] comboStrings = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    public List<String> ComboStrings
    {
       get { return new List<string>(comboStrings); }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        BrowserCombo.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // BrowserCombo.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

I want to have it very simple, so no MVVM - I still need to learn this concept.

Remarks:

1. I can put *SelectedIndex* in the XAML file. Same problem.
2. If I put the *SelectedIndex* in the *Page_Loaded* event handler, it works fine.
3. In a classic desktop XAML (aka WPF) there will be no problem.

It seems to be that the item list will be populated differently between XAML-WinRt and XAML-WPF. What is the earliest point to access the *SelectedIndex* property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this exception because your *ItemsSource* is still *null* when you try to set `BrowserCombo.SelectedIndex = 1;` in the page's constructor. You are using `x:Bind` - if you debug the generated *MainPage.g.cs* file and put some breakpoints there:

```cs
public void Loading(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement src, object data)
{
    this.Initialize();
}

public void Initialize()
{
    if (!this.initialized)
    {
        this.Update();
    }
}

public void Update()
{
    this.Update_(this.dataRoot, NOT_PHASED);
    this.initialized = true;
}
```

You will see that `x:Bind` is being resolved in *Loading* event - this explains why in constructor you still have *null* in *ItemsSource*.

The other thing is that with old *Binding* - it is resolved when you set `DataContext = this;`, but you are using `x:Bind` and in fact you don't need to set the *DataContext* - it doesn't change anything here. If you replace `ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboStrings}"` with `ItemsSource="{Binding ComboStrings}"` then your code should work, otherwise you may remove the line `DataContext = this;`.

Another interesting thing is that the order of defined bindings in XAML, can also cause similar troubles - for example if you define your *ComboBox* like this:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="BrowserCombo" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind Index}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboStrings}">
```

then you will also get exception - *SelectedIndex* is being resolved before the collection is set up. Opposite to the situation when it works fine:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="BrowserCombo" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ComboStrings}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind Index}">
```